# How to read a particular column in a csv file in robotframework and if they are in list How to seperate it as a string

Tags: xpath, robotframework

How to read a particular column in a excel file in robotframework and if they are in list How to seperate it as a string

${read}=    Read Csv File   ${readcsv}
output it returns like this:first_name,last_name,email_id,manager_email,organization_unit,grade,title
RamuGovidan,,kartest2234+2ramu@gmail.com,kartest2234+2ramu@gmail.com,3dtalentservices,A2,ceoAjith,,kartest2234+2ajith@gmail....

How to get Like                                                               Ramu
                                                                amudhan like this. how to eliminate comma from here and return only string

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this using [`String`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html) library keywords. Using `Replace String` is probably the cleanest and simplest solution:

```
${read}=    Read Csv File    ${readcsv}
${read}=    Replace String    ${read}    ,    ${SPACE}
Log To Console    ${read}
```

Comment: it returns error 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'.